# Symfony 2 Previous URL

Tags: php, url, symfony

How to check in symfony2 controller previous URL, like in symfony 1.x ?
Something equivalent to:

```
$request->getReferer();
```

Comment: The `$request` should have an `headers` property, the HTTP_REFERER should be in there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To check controller previous URL in **symfony 2** :

```
$this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer')
```

Comment: Be aware that malicious users can change the referer header.

Answer (score 2):

In new version of symfony the request object should be injected!

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
        $request->headers->get('referer');
        //...
}
```